# TSQL query working fine for one database but when running under sp_msforeachdb procedure, failing with incorrect syntax but the syntax is correct

Tags: t-sql

I have a sql query which work fine for one database. But I want to run against all databases and that's why would like to run under sp_msforeachdb to loop through all databases. But under this procedure query is failing.

I have tried running the query without the sp_msforeachdb and no issues. But I want to loop through all databases.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use ''?'' SELECT ''SV1'' AS SERVER_NAME, 
   ''IN1'' AS instance_number, 
   ''?'' AS database_name, 
   s.name AS SCHEMA_NAME, 
   t.name AS TABLE_NAME, 
   c.name AS COLUMN_NAME,
   CASE
       WHEN(c.name LIKE ''%addr%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%area%code%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%city%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%e-mail%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%email%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%mobile%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%cell%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%phone%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%postal%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%street%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%zip%'')
       THEN ''Contact Info''
       WHEN(c.name LIKE ''%birthday%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%date%of%birth%''
            OR c.name = ''dob'')
       THEN ''Date of Birth''
       WHEN(c.name LIKE ''%clinic%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%health%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%healthcondition%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%medical%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%medication%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%patient%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%prescription%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%treatment%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%first%name%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%last%name%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%maiden%name%''
            OR c.name LIKE ''%surname%'')
       THEN ''Health''
   END AS Information_type_name
FROM sys.columns c LEFT JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id WHERE t.type IN(''U'', ''V'')'
```

I have formatted the query for easier to read after reading stackoverflow rules.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you run the query with sp_msforeachdb

Answer (score 1):

Your query is very poorly formatted.
There is a comma before the from clause which seems to be the problem. Here is the formatted SQL

```
SELECT 'SV1' AS SERVER_NAME, 
   'IN1' AS instance_number, 
   '?' AS database_name, 
   s.name AS SCHEMA_NAME, 
   t.name AS TABLE_NAME, 
   c.name AS COLUMN_NAME,
   CASE
       WHEN(c.name LIKE '%addr%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%area%code%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%city%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%e-mail%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%email%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%mobile%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%cell%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%phone%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%postal%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%street%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%zip%')
       THEN 'Contact Info'
       WHEN(c.name LIKE '%birthday%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%date%of%birth%'
            OR c.name = 'dob')
       THEN 'Date of Birth'
       WHEN(c.name LIKE '%clinic%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%health%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%healthcondition%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%medical%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%medication%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%patient%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%prescription%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%treatment%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%first%name%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%last%name%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%maiden%name%'
            OR c.name LIKE '%surname%')
       THEN 'Health'
   END AS Information_type_name
```

FROM sys.columns c
     LEFT JOIN sys.tables`enter code here` t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.type IN('U', 'V');

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I just learned how to format code in stackoverflow. Now back to my question, yes the comma was left by mistake since I took part of the code. The issue is query work fine when running directly but not under the procedure sp_msforeachdb. Can I get some insights on this why not working under procedure